# Users list, follow button not working properly

Tags: php, button, twitter-follow

I've created a page which displays all the users on the site.

The **user_id** and the **username** is displayed for each user. I tried adding a **follow** button at the side of each user and in order to **follow** someone it grabs their **user_id**.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work because the **user_id** which is being grabbed is always the **last one** from the **database**, because of the loop.

So if you press the **follow** button for **anyone** on the list, it will always **follow** the **last** person.

How can I fix this?

I've been trying different methods for more than 20 hours but they all seem to have the same problem...

Here is the code:

```
<?php
 class Database()
 {
    // connect
    // query

    public function fetchAll() {
       $this->rows = $this->result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
       return $this->rows;
    }

    public function display() {
      $this->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
      $this->fetchAll();
    }
 }

 $class = new Database();

 $users = $class->display();

 foreach ($users as $user) {
   $user_id = $user['user_id'];
   $username = $user['username'];

   echo $user_id . ' ' . $username;
   echo '<form action="" method="post">';
   echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
   echo '</form>';
 }

 if ($_POST['follow']) {
   $FClass->follow($user_id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that makes sense.

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_id = $user['user_id']; // At the end of the loop this is the last user
    $username = $user['username'];

    echo $user_id . ' ' . $username;
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
    echo '</form>';
}

if ($_POST['follow']) {
    // Regardless of what you input you're getting the last user here
    $FClass->follow($user_id); 
}
```

Try something like this

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_id = $user['user_id']; // At the end of the loop this is the last user
    $username = $user['username'];

    echo $user_id . ' ' . $username;
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="' . $user_id . '">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="' . $user_id . '">';
    echo '</form>';
}

if ($_POST['follow']) {
    // Regardless of what you input you're getting the last user here
    error_log($_POST['follow']); // View your logs to verify
    $FClass->follow($_POST['follow']); 
    // or
    $FClass->follow($_POST['userid']);
}
```

Comment: In that form you're never actually submitting the username.  You could even use hidden fields.  I'll edit to reflect.

Comment: Thanks man! It works now! I don't quite understand how it works, but it does.

Comment: No problem.  You were never sending any information with your form on submission so you never got anything back to your php to reference.